# Windows Azure application - Hack attempt?

Tags: windows, security, azure

We have our application hosted in Windows Azure and it is working well. Recently we have started seeing some suspicious requests to our application. Requests are for resources that don't exist in our application.

We have started seeing exceptions like :

```
Message: The file '/a1b2c3d4.asmx' does not exist.

Message: The file '/CrystalReportWebFormViewer2/crystalimagehandler.aspx' does not exist.

Message: The file '/login.aspx' does not exist.

Message: This is an invalid webresource request.
```

We dont have any `.asmx` files or Crystal Reports in our application. Additionally, all the requests are coming from `100.69.14.169` which doesn't exist at all.

This is happening frequently now. We are not sure if this is an hacking attempt or some automated scripts trying something with our Azure application.

Could you please help us to understand what these requests are and how to stop them?

Comment: Probably just a script kiddy run against your website. Basically, they have a huge list of files in particular applications that had vulnerabilities. They just make requests for all of these files to every server they can find. *if* they get a response for any of these files, and they appear to be the vulnerable application, *then* they may investigate the site more thoroughly and try to attack it.

Comment: I get these too, many known php / wordpress / joomla exploit addresses despite being a .net site. Would like to know how "This is an invalid webresource request." errors are even triggered.

Answer (score 1):

In the web.config file, you can use the [requestFiltering](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering) element to apply a behavior to the request.

It allows you fairly extensive control.  The only difference is that on Azure this functionality is implemented via the web.config rather than through a management console.

You can use the [filteringRules](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/filteringrules)'s denyStrings element to define sequences where your app should return a 404 in response.

```
   <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>              
                    <filteringRules>
                        <filteringRule name="BlockAUrl" scanUrl="true" scanQueryString="false">
                            <denyStrings>                                   
                                <add string="/Manage/ScriptKitty/Attempted/Login.aspx" />
                            </denyStrings>
                        </filteringRule>
                    </filteringRules>               
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue as the OP, and this was definitely helpful.  It ensured we're returning a standard 404, but it's nice to know we can control these things from a config perspective out in the Azure world.